# Undelete and reopen an "off-topic" question that has happened ~half a year later as a big political event? Germany’s condemnation of the Holodomor

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen

This is about [Have there been public political/medial events/debates over Holodomor as crime or genocide triggered by Russia's aggressions against Ukrainian land?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71193/have-there-been-public-political-medial-events-debates-over-holodomor-as-crime-o) which was asked on 2022-02-28 and was closed as off-topic.

A strong event as an answer to the war in Ukraine happened in Germany on 2022-11-30.

> [Germany declares Ukraine's Holodomor famine a genocide](https://www.dw.com/en/germany-declares-stalin-era-holodomor-famine-in-ukraine-a-genocide/a-63944665)
> ...
> Germany’s condemnation of the Holodomor is intended as a “warning” to Russian President Vladimir Putin, as the war rages on in Ukraine.
> ...
> Among other things, Wednesday's resolution calls on the German government to work against "any attempts to spread a one-sided Russian historical narrative'' and to keep supporting Ukraine as a victim of the current war.

See also other search hits, one randomly picked is [Germany to Declare the Holodomor in Soviet Ukraine a Genocide](https://greekreporter.com/2022/11/26/germany-holodomor-soviet-ukraine-genocide/).

I have voted to undelete and reopen and also flagged it to be checked by a moderator. I do not see any point why this question, which was proven on-topic by time, should stay closed, if there is even at least one strong event as an answer to it which was clearly linked to the war in Ukraine.

Comment: TBH I've been a bit shocked at how the perception/presentation of the war in Chechnya has change on German TV in the last year or so  https://youtu.be/3K7bWTSnxU8?t=157 , including comparing Kadyrov with the Islamic State. So, yeah, the longer this war in Ukraine drags on, the more negative image Russia's history is going to get from other angles, as well, at least in the minds of some Europeans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not going to undelete or reopen the question because I don't believe that it is a real question. To me it looks like just an attempt to create awareness for the Holodomor and draw parallels to the current Russian invasion of Ukraine.

Not that there is anything wrong with that in general. The Holodomor was an abhorrent violation of human rights by the Soviet Union, and the Russian invasion of Ukraine is as well. But Politics Stack Exchange is not the place for that. This is a question&answer website, not a platform for political activism.

Comment: The *question* is just a one-liner, the rest is what I knew about it. Mind that at that time, there was no such awareness about Holodomor at all. My aim was to find a current political link from the war to such events. And that is a truely political question. Mind that this has happened, thus, you cannot doubt that the question does not fit. What does not fit as to your answer is anything I put beside the question. Which is not the question.

Comment: There is a comment with many upvotes which only debates whether it is genocide at all, but that is just a reply to what I put beside the question. The main rule if you ask a question on Stack Exchange is to show what you know about it. You call it political activism, I call it knowing that almost nobody knew about Holodomor at all at that time, and it then was misunderstood as a debate on genocide. Which is not the question.

Comment: I have shrunk it down to the question and the core wikipedia facts of the time of asking in February, taking out my own findings and taking out what you called activism (what I call just the background why I was seeing a chance for the events). If a "back-in-time question like this is not possible, I can shrink it down further to the question itself, without anything around it, since that would be timeless. Hope you check it again to reopen.

Comment: I took out the "back-in-time" meta noise. That is easier to understand. Now, there are just answers missing about the 50000 petition that was known at the time of asking the question in the first place and the known events in November 2022.

Comment: I marked this as an answer, but mind that making a link between Holodomor and the invasion was not from an activist view, but rather from a statistical one: if since Holodomor, there has been Russian immigration into a then weakened area (and the whole area had to be weakened since else, farmers of the broad area around it would have taken back the land) and these Russian immigrants ended up building the main share after 90 years, while at the beginning, there were no Russian speakers in this area. The invasion took those areas with a high Russian share. If that does not sound like a plan.

Comment: @ETathome A plan? So you think Stalin anticipated the creation of NATO, the fall of the Soviet Union, the NATO east expansion, Euromaidan, Ukraine looking to get closer to the EU and his successors desire to annex parts of Ukraine 90 years in advance? Quite playing the long game... Stalin was quite the schemer indeed, but don't you think you are giving him a bit *too* much credit?

Comment: It is not about planning these political steps as they happened. It is about the outcome that shows a plan. And yes, right after Holodomor, the area was settled by White Russians and Russians. Some went back when finding the dead - and you would not go back for that after travelling hundreds of kilometers with your family, rather, if you knew that this was a forced hunger so that it nagged on your conscience. No Russian speakers 90 years ago. The taken area is the area that was geopolitically wished, then and now. Hitler also wanted a link to the Krim. They both wanted to get to the Black Sea.